# Is there a way to restrict access to a Wear OS app?

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I released an update to my app that adapted to different types of screens, including small ones, but now I have a problem: Google Play Console recognizes my app as Wear OS, even though I haven't optimized it for that platform.
Is there a way to restrict access to a Wear OS app?
[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify on what recognise means in this context? On which pages of play developer console is your app being treated like a wear app? 

Also feel free to file a bug via - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/gethelp

Comment: The issue is fixed now. Could you please check and confirm? Thanks.

Comment: @dsharew Sorry for the long answer. When I uploaded the application to open testing, Google started testing it for Wear OS devices, and it failed because I did not develop it for these devices.

Comment: @dsharew I checked the device directory and there are no Wear OS devices that support my app.

Comment: So you are still experiencing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use the Device Catalog in Google Play Store.
You can go to the Device catalog page by using (Release > Reach and devices > Device catalog), and set it to be manually excluded.

Guide:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en

Alternatively you might be able to trick Wear OS into marking your app unsupported by setting something like a Camera to be a required feature. I am not certain of this one though.

Comment: I've already looked at that list, but there are no available devices, but Google is testing my app on Wear OS devices and has started sending me various messages about Wear OS.